# Line Graph Between Two Dates

Tags: android

I have two dates and according to these dates I have to draw a graph like 
Date on x-Axis and on Y-axis I have purchases. For graph I have used **MpChart Lib** and its working fine but I have no idea how to calculate date for x-Axis

Example:

1st situation: If I have dates 2018-03-23 and 2018-03-28 then difference is in days so how x-Axis should be calculated for MpChart.

2nd situation: If I have dates 2017-12-23 and 2018-03-28 then difference is in weeks so how x-Axis should be calculated for MpChart.

3rd situation: If I have dates 2017-01-01 and 2018-03-28 then difference is in year so how x-Axis should be calculated for MpChart.

**For Now I have this:**

```
 private void setData(int count, float range) {

        ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            values.add(new Entry(i, (int) (Math.random() * 65) + 40));
        }

        LineDataSet set1;

        if (mChart.getData() != null &&
                mChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
            set1 = (LineDataSet) mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
            set1.setValues(values);
            mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            // create a dataset and give it a type
            set1 = new LineDataSet(values, " ");

            set1.setDrawIcons(false);

            // set the line to be drawn like this "- - - - - -"
            //set1.enableDashedLine(10f, 5f, 0f);
            //set1.enableDashedHighlightLine(10f, 5f, 0f);
            set1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            // set1.setCircleColor(Color.BLACK);
            set1.setLineWidth(1f);
            // set1.setCircleRadius(3f);
            // set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);
            set1.setDrawCircles(false);
            set1.setValueTextSize(9f);
            set1.setDrawFilled(true);
            set1.setFormLineWidth(1f);
            set1.setFormLineDashEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{10f, 5f}, 0f));
            set1.setFormSize(15.f);
            set1.setDrawValues(false);
            if (Utils.getSDKInt() >= 18) {
                // fill drawable only supported on api level 18 and above
                Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.fade_red);
                set1.setFillDrawable(drawable);
            } else {
                set1.setFillColor(Color.BLACK);
            }

            ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
            dataSets.add(set1); // add the datasets

            // create a data object with the datasets
            LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);

            // set data
            mChart.setData(data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

MPAndroidChart library is a pretty good chart/graph library with many formatting options, and yes it has the option to format X-axis data to date values too, even you can format it to any type of data you want. You just need to create your own custom XAxisValueFormatter class which will implement IAxisValueFormatter interface, but remember you'll need to get date in timestamp for this to work, and it's pretty easy to convert dates to timestamp.

Here's the example: MyXAxisValueFormatter.java

```
public class MyXAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
    try {
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/yy");           // format your date the way you want
        Long valueLong = (long) value;                  // cast your date value to long
        return sdf.format(new Date(valueLong));         // return the formatted date
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return String.valueOf(value);                   // if any error occurs, return the value as it is 
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your main class, add the following line:

```
XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter());
xAxis.setLabelCount(4, true);    // it will force the chart to show only 4 date labels on X-Axis
```

Here setLabelCount method will automatically find the range for x-axis based on your data, so you don't really have to pre-calculate and define it in your setData method.

[You can find more detailed info here.](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/789)